# Unable to change Font Color of text while writing to excel file using Java

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I have a requirement to take the test data from Excel sheet and write test result as Pass/Fail in another Excel sheet.
I am using SeleniumRC+Java+Eclipse+Junit.

How can i change font color of text while writing to Excel sheet using Java.

I am doing with the help of Label, WorkBook, WrittableWorkbook, WrittableSheet, Sheet.

Here is my sample code..

```
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class FinalTestSuite extends TestCase 
{
public static  File file = new File("C:/Selenium/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3/TestingResult.xls");
public static  File sourceFile = new File("C:/Selenium/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3/Portland.xls");
public static  WorkbookSettings ws;
public static  WritableWorkbook workbook;
public static  WritableSheet wSheet1, wSheet2;
public static  Sheet sh1, sh2;
public static  Sheet sheetFinal;
public static  Workbook sourceWorkbook;
public static  Label label;
}


public void getTestResult(String passOrfail) throws IOException,BiffException, WriteException

{
try
{

FinalTestSuite.file = new File("C:/Selenium/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3/TestingResult.xls");
FinalTestSuite.sourceFile = new File("C:/Selenium/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3/TestDetails.xls");
FinalTestSuite.ws = new WorkbookSettings();
FinalTestSuite.workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(FinalTestSuite.file, FinalTestSuite.ws);
                FinalTestSuite.sourceWorkbook=Workbook.getWorkbook(FinalTestSuite.sourceFile);
FinalTestSuite.sh1 = FinalTestSuite.sourceWorkbook.getSheet(0);
FinalTestSuite.sh2= FinalTestSuite.sourceWorkbook.getSheet(1);
FinalTestSuite.wSheet1 = FinalTestSuite.workbook.importSheet("Begin", 0 , FinalTestSuite.sh1);
FinalTestSuite.wSheet2 = FinalTestSuite.workbook.importSheet("Reports", 0 , FinalTestSuite.sh2);
colCount = FinalTestSuite.wSheet2.getColumns();

rowCount = FinalTestSuite.wSheet2.getRows();

                for(col=1;col<=colCount;col++)
                {

                    for(row = 1;row<=rowCount;row++)
                    {
                        jxl.Cell dataCell =  FinalTestSuite.wSheet2.getCell(col, 0);

                        if(clientName.equals(client))
                        {
                            FinalTestSuite.label = new Label(col, row, passOrfail);
                            FinalTestSuite.wSheet2.addCell(FinalTestSuite.label);
                            break;                          


                        }

                    }
                }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please anybody tell me how can i modify it to get Test result with font color as red and green...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `WritableFont.setColour(Colour colour)` when formatting the cell you're writing to. See [this tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#formatting%20cells) for the basics. The API should be sufficient to know how to add a colour to the formatting examples available.

Comment: Thanks Wim.. it really worked out.. 

WritableFont fontColor = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 10, WritableFont.BOLD);
fontColor.setColour(Colour.RED);
WritableCellFormat newFormat = new WritableCellFormat(fontColor);
FinalTestSuite.wSheet2.addCell(new Label(col, row, contents, newFormat));

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe for reference you can add that piece of code to your original post in an edit? Cheers